# How to store user input if it was something like an email address? So I can call it later?

Tags: java, arrays, email, split, user-input

```
String[] array = new String[2];               
System.out.println("Email please: ");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = sc.next();
System.out.println(array[1]);
```

when I enter an email for example "email@gmail.com" it returns null what am I missing?

Comment: The email is in `array[0]`

Comment: What is `sc`? If you are referring to `Scanner.class` you might as well do `String email =  sc.nextLine()`